# Change priority for drawing border

Tags: html, css

I want draw `<div>` border over `<li>` border.
Now it see like that:
[image]
But i want draw that:
[image]
All my code on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkp7fn9v/):

```css
#mainmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#mainmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120pt;
  height: 20pt;
  padding: 10pt 0pt 10pt 0pt;
  border: 2px gray solid;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 130pt;
  display: block;
}
#mainmenu h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0px;
}
#mainmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Семинар 1</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Задача 1</li>
        <li>Задача 2</li>
        <li>Задача 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Семинар 2</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Задача 1</li>
        <li>Задача 2</li>
        <li>Задача 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Big thanks for your response!

Comment: could you add `border-left:2px red solid;` to your `#mainmenu ul li:hover ul{}` selector?

Comment: OMG :) It bad solution. http://i.imgur.com/PHsbk1Z.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Image:**

[image]

**From your image (that I have posted above), I believe you are looking for something like this:**

```css
#mainmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#mainmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120pt;
  height: 20pt;
  padding: 10pt 0pt 10pt 0pt;
}
ul li ul li {
  border: 2px gray solid;
  margin-left:6px;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 130pt;
  display: block;
}
#mainmenu h1 {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index:2;
}
#mainmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 6px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Семинар 1</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Задача 1</li>
        <li>Задача 2</li>
        <li>Задача 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Семинар 2</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Задача 1</li>
        <li>Задача 2</li>
        <li>Задача 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your screenshot, I'm guessing you're trying to change the border-color of the left-most boxes.

Rather than "covering" up the gray border with a red one, I'd recommend specifically targeting those top-level `<li>`s with CSS, and setting the border of those elements to red. You can use the CSS direct descendant selector to do that:

```
#mainmenu > ul > li {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

---

**Full Example Below (click "run code snippet")**:

```css
#mainmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#mainmenu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120pt;
    height: 20pt;
    padding: 10pt 0pt 10pt 0pt;
    border: 2px gray solid;
}

#mainmenu > ul > li {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#mainmenu ul li:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 130pt;
    display: block;
}
#mainmenu h1 {
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 0px;
}

#mainmenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><h1>Семинар 1</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Задача 1</li>
                <li>Задача 2</li>
                <li>Задача 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><h1>Семинар 2</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Задача 1</li>
                <li>Задача 2</li>
                <li>Задача 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "no"? What specifically are you looking for that is different than the answer I posted?

Comment: Yes. Results are different

Comment: I think that difference is in position of `ul` contents. In author examples, the _Red_ line draws **above** the _Gray_ line. In your case, _Red_ line draws **near** to _Gray_ line.

Comment: @Beezy ah yeah, maybe so. I didn't think of the spacing. You could control that with margins.

Comment: @StevenSchobert, how you can see, I up voted your answer)